# Recyrcleview dinâmico android

Tags: android

Preciso fazer um recyrcleview um dentro de outro na vertical mais como isso como já sitado em outros lugares não vai funcionar. E o expandable list view no meu caso não atende minha necessidade porque irá ter várias particularidades.

Comecei a utilizar o LayoutInflater e consegui fazer isso que eu queria a parte interna dinâmica mais a parte externa dele eu só consigo de forma manual e eu precisava fazer isso de forma dinâmica porque como vai ser gerado com dados que iram vim do banco de dados não sei se vai ter 1 ou mil cabeçalhos com dados dentro, e no meu código a seguir possui apenas para 2 e se precisasse para mais iria precisar fazer de forma manual. Não sei se consegui  ser claro. Agradeço desde já!

Minha MainActivity.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ArrayList<Resultado> lista1 = new ArrayList<Resultado>();
private ArrayList<Resultado> lista2 = new ArrayList<Resultado>();

private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
private DynamicListAdapter mDynamicListAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyrcleview);

    lista1 = Utils.preencherLista1();
    lista2 = Utils.preencherLista2();

    mDynamicListAdapter = new DynamicListAdapter();
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mDynamicListAdapter);
}

private class DynamicListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private static final int ITEM_RESULTADO_VIEW1 = 1;
    private static final int ITEM_RESULTADO_CABECALHO_VIEW1 = 2;
    private static final int ITEM_RESULTADO_VIEW2 = 3;
    private static final int ITEM_RESULTADO_CABECALHO_VIEW2 = 4;

    public DynamicListAdapter() {
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView txtDescricao;
        private TextView txtTitulo;

        public ViewHolder(final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            txtDescricao = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.descricao);
            txtTitulo = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.titulo);
        }

        public void bindViewSecondList(int pos) {

            if (lista1 == null) pos = pos - 1;
            else {
                if (lista1.size() == 0) pos = pos - 1;
                else pos = pos - lista1.size() - 2;
            }

            final String descricao = lista2.get(pos).getDescricao();
            final String titulo = lista2.get(pos).getTitulo();
            txtDescricao.setText(descricao);
            txtTitulo.setText(titulo);
        }

        public void bindViewFirstList(int pos) {
            pos = pos - 1;

            final String descricao = lista1.get(pos).getDescricao();
            final String titulo = lista1.get(pos).getTitulo();

            txtDescricao.setText(descricao);
            txtTitulo.setText(titulo);
        }

    }

    private class ItemCabecalhoLista1ViewHolder extends ViewHolder {
        public ItemCabecalhoLista1ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
        }
    }

    private class ItemLista1ViewHolder extends ViewHolder {
        public ItemLista1ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
        }
    }

    private class ItemCabecalhoLista2ViewHolder extends ViewHolder {
        public ItemCabecalhoLista2ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
        }
    }

    private class ItemLista2ViewHolder extends ViewHolder {
        public ItemLista2ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View v;
        if (viewType == ITEM_RESULTADO_VIEW1) {
            v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_resultado, parent, false);
            ItemLista1ViewHolder vh = new ItemLista1ViewHolder(v);
            return vh;

        } else if (viewType == ITEM_RESULTADO_CABECALHO_VIEW1) {
            v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_resultado_cabecalho, parent, false);
            ItemCabecalhoLista1ViewHolder vh = new ItemCabecalhoLista1ViewHolder(v);
            return vh;

        } else if (viewType == ITEM_RESULTADO_CABECALHO_VIEW2) {
            v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_resultado_cabecalho, parent, false);
            ItemCabecalhoLista2ViewHolder vh = new ItemCabecalhoLista2ViewHolder(v);
            return vh;

        } else {
            v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_resultado, parent, false);
            ItemLista2ViewHolder vh = new ItemLista2ViewHolder(v);
            return vh;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        try {
            if (holder instanceof ItemLista2ViewHolder) {
                ItemLista2ViewHolder vh = (ItemLista2ViewHolder) holder;
                vh.bindViewSecondList(position);

            } else if (holder instanceof ItemCabecalhoLista1ViewHolder) {
                ItemCabecalhoLista1ViewHolder vh = (ItemCabecalhoLista1ViewHolder) holder;

            } else if (holder instanceof ItemLista1ViewHolder) {
                ItemLista1ViewHolder vh = (ItemLista1ViewHolder) holder;
                vh.bindViewFirstList(position);

            } else if (holder instanceof ItemCabecalhoLista2ViewHolder) {
                ItemCabecalhoLista2ViewHolder vh = (ItemCabecalhoLista2ViewHolder) holder;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {

        int tamanhoLista1 = 0;
        int tamanhoLista2 = 0;

        if (lista2 == null && lista1 == null) return 0;

        if (lista2 != null)
            tamanhoLista2 = lista2.size();
        if (lista1 != null)
            tamanhoLista1 = lista1.size();

        if (tamanhoLista2 > 0 && tamanhoLista1 > 0)
            return 1 + tamanhoLista1 + 1 + tamanhoLista2 + 1;
        else if (tamanhoLista2 > 0 && tamanhoLista1 == 0)
            return 1 + tamanhoLista2 + 1;
        else if (tamanhoLista2 == 0 && tamanhoLista1 > 0)
            return 1 + tamanhoLista1;
        else return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {

        int tamanhoLista1 = 0;
        int tamanhoLista2 = 0;

        if (lista2 == null && lista1 == null)
            return super.getItemViewType(position);

        if (lista2 != null)
            tamanhoLista2 = lista2.size();
        if (lista1 != null)
            tamanhoLista1 = lista1.size();

        if (tamanhoLista2 > 0 && tamanhoLista1 > 0) {
            if (position == 0) return ITEM_RESULTADO_CABECALHO_VIEW1;
            else if (position == tamanhoLista1 + 1)
                return ITEM_RESULTADO_CABECALHO_VIEW2;
            else if (position > tamanhoLista1 + 1)
                return ITEM_RESULTADO_VIEW2;
            else return ITEM_RESULTADO_VIEW1;

        } else if (tamanhoLista2 > 0 && tamanhoLista1 == 0) {
            if (position == 0) return ITEM_RESULTADO_CABECALHO_VIEW2;
            else return ITEM_RESULTADO_VIEW1;

        } else if (tamanhoLista2 == 0 && tamanhoLista1 > 0) {
            if (position == 0) return ITEM_RESULTADO_CABECALHO_VIEW1;
            else return ITEM_RESULTADO_VIEW1;
        }
        return super.getItemViewType(position);
    }
}
```

Model

```
public class Resultado {
private String titulo;
private String descricao;


public Resultado(String titulo, String descricao) {
    this.setTitulo(titulo);
    this.setDescricao(descricao);
}

public String getTitulo() {
    return titulo;
}

public void setTitulo(String titulo) {
    this.titulo = titulo;
}

public String getDescricao() {
    return descricao;
}

public void setDescricao(String descricao) {
    this.descricao = descricao;
}
```

E a classe que eu utilizo para  preencher

```
public class Utils {

public static ArrayList<Resultado> preencherLista1() {
    ArrayList<Resultado> mFirstList = new ArrayList<Resultado>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        Resultado mResultado = new Resultado(" " + i, "Descricão " + i);
        mFirstList.add(mResultado);
    }
    return mFirstList;
}

public static ArrayList<Resultado> preencherLista2() {
    ArrayList<Resultado> mSecondList = new ArrayList<Resultado>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        Resultado mResultado = new Resultado(" " + i, "Descricão " + i);
        mSecondList.add(mResultado);
    }
    return mSecondList;
}
```

View principal

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="inovace.masudias.com.dynamicrecyclerview.MainActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyrcleview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Item

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="5px"
android:orientation="horizontal">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/titulo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/descricao"
    android:paddingLeft="10px"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_dark" />
```

item cabeçalho

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Cabeçalho "
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="bold|italic" />
```

Comment: Voce consegue fazer isso com o expandable recyclerview. A parte que vai expandir é dinamica.

Comment: Não sei se fui claro com oque eu quero mais se o expandable recyclerview tiver a opção de deixar todos expandidos sem o usuário clicar para abrir iria resolver meu problema